# Want to preserve bashrc and vimrc when switching to non-root users

Tags: bash, sudo, users, su

I'm on a multi-user system. I have sudo b/c I'm responsible I guess. Sometimes, I want to switch to another user to help them do something, but I have a tricked-out bashrc/vimrc and I'd like to keep those.

For root, it's pretty easy. In my `.bashrc`:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
alias -- -i='bash --rcfile $HOME/.bashrc'
export HOME="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null && pwd )"
```

Basically, this means `sudo -i` makes me root, sources my `.bashrc`, and keeps my `$HOME` as `/home/jeremy` instead of `/root`, meaning vim looks in the proper place for colors and rcfiles and things.

I want to do something similar with becoming other users. The ideal:

- source *my* `.bashrc`; get vim to use *my* `.vim/` stuff like `vimrc`, `colors/`, etc.
- doesn't hardcode paths -- on some systems I'm `jeremy`; on others I'm `jdr`, etc.
- requires minimal extra typing for all of this to work by aliasing or function-ing the crap out of things.

For root, I was able to alias `-i` to another command entirely that did what I wanted.  `man bash` doesn't list any options to do things as another user. `man sudo` does, but then I wouldn't have any options to source a `.bashrc`. `su` seemed promising, as `man su` says that `su -m` preserves environment and doesn't set USER or HOME, but I'd have to `sudo su -m` which sets my USER to `root`. I can't add in commands using `&&` or something because I would need the commands to run in the new shell instead of after that shell exits. In short, none of the commands I know of can do what I want.

The closest I was able to come was `sudo -Esu user`, which makes me `user` and keeps any vars I've exported. I could put something like `export x=". $HOME/.bashrc"` in my `.bashrc` and then `eval $x` when I become `user`, but that gives permissions errors, and setting +x on `.bashrc` isn't sufficient because my home directory's default permissions prevent access by other users and I'm not sure I'd want to change that unless there's no other option. Not all users I'm becoming have privileges so I can't just `sudo` my way in.

**TL;DR:** become another user while retaining my current user's aliases, functions, PS1, PROMPT_COMMAND, and vim configuration. Bash 4.2

Comment: If you want to help your users, perhaps share your .vimrc and .bashrc settings with them?

Comment: Meaning just shove a copy to their home directories? My settings are in flux as I learn and experiment more, and I don't want to have to remember to update it as I change it, or push it to new users as they are added. It feels like there should be a better option than making my .bashrc and .vimrc symlinks to files that everyone has at least execute access to.